# ¿Por qué un informe funciona en iReport (desarrollo) y da un error ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente en JasperServer?

Tags: oracle

¿Por qué un informe funciona en iReport (desarrollo) y  da un error `ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente` en JasperServer?

La consulta es la misma. Devuelve datos correctos en iReport y al ejecutarlo en el servidor JasperServ, indica error ORA-00933.

---

Tanto iReport como JasperServer se encuentran en el mismo servidor, la conexión comprobada y es correcta para ambos. A raíz de introducir un Input control para introducir un parámetro, cambió el comportamiento. La consulta se ejecuta correctamente en iReport, pero en el servidor Jasper me da el error anteriormente indicado: ORA-00933. Es cierto que el error es claro: consulta incorrecta, pero esa misma consulta la ejecuto en SQL Developer y corre perfectamente. Me desconcierta un poco, no tiene ";" al final de la consulta. La he revisado varias veces y no acabo de ver el error.
Supongo que optaré por limpiar de nuevo la consulta y hacerla de nuevo, pero ¿no es para vosotros un poco árido el comportamiento de JasperServer?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No te falta info en la pregunta?? por ejemplo, que es ese error??? las bases son identicas??

Comment: Pulsá en [edit] para agregar más detalles a tu pregunta, ya que actualmente es muy ambigua: ¿son las mismas conexiones, o son bases de datos distintas? ¿Cuál es la consulta SQL?

Comment: Con la información proporcionada, diría que porque no está bien hecho. Si quieres una respuesta más detallada, entonces, incluir más información en la pregunta.

Comment: En tu consulta ¿usas parámetros de reporte? Revisa el jasperserver.log y complementa tu pregunta.